# Angular ui router going to default route always

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have about 20 route in my application, however from about the 15 routes and over every time i navigate i get redirected to the default root, and when i try again , doing the same steps as at first i can now navigate to the route. So my question is does angular has a finite number of routing that are possible.

Below is one of the routes i am using.

```
$stateProvider.state('checklist-details', {
    url: '/checklist-details/:idChecklist/:modeOfScreen',
    parent: 'root',
    views: {
        'mainContent': {
            templateUrl: 'modules/app/views/checklist-details.html',
            controller: 'checklistDetailsController',
            resolve: {
                factory: checkRouting
            }
        }
    }
}); //END state
```

Comment: are you sure it's not with your `checkRouting` variable? Shouldn't it be a function call anyway? Routes can rejected if it couldn't resolve what's inside in the `resolve`.

Comment: What is the order of your routes? It matters which one is first, last, etc... especially if you have parameters. If you have a route `/checklist-details/something/:idChecklist` after that one, then the word 'something' will be treated as id for the previous route and there should be an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If it's redirecting to default view, there should be an error on console output. What is the error?